# Access denied exception while trying to access the login page in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, access-denied, spring-java-config

I am using java based spring security. I have created the custom access decision voter impl.

But when I run the application, I can not open the login page as it says, access is denied.

This happened after I added the custom access decision voter impl. I guess the issue is because of the following code in custom AccessDecisionVoter.

```
if(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)
            return ACCESS_DENIED;
```

But i need this so that permissions are not checked for not logged in users.

And it goes in infinite loop, login page, access decision voter, access denied, login page and so on.

Below is the spring security configuration code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager;

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager(AccessDecisionVoterImpl accessDecisionVoter) {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<?>> accessDecisionVoters = new ArrayList<AccessDecisionVoter<?>>();
        accessDecisionVoters.add(accessDecisionVoter);
        AffirmativeBased accessDecisionManager = new AffirmativeBased(accessDecisionVoters);
        return accessDecisionManager;
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new PasswordEncoder();
        passwordEncoder.setStringDigester(stringDigester());
        return passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public PooledStringDigester stringDigester() {
        PooledStringDigester psd = new PooledStringDigester();

        psd.setPoolSize(2);
        psd.setAlgorithm("SHA-256");
        psd.setIterations(1000);
        psd.setSaltSizeBytes(16);
        psd.setSaltGenerator(randomSaltGenerator());

        return psd;
    }

    @Bean
    public RandomSaltGenerator randomSaltGenerator() {
        RandomSaltGenerator randomSaltGenerator = new RandomSaltGenerator();
        return randomSaltGenerator;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/static/**")
                .antMatchers("/i18n/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/checkLogin")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .failureUrl("/login?login_error=1")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?isLoggedOut=1")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .permitAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/error**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/checkLogin**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager)
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied")
        .and()
            .headers()
            .frameOptions()
            .disable()
        .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .invalidSessionUrl("/login")
            .maximumSessions(1);
    }

}
```

and my custom voter impl

```
@Component
public class AccessDecisionVoterImpl implements AccessDecisionVoter {

    @Autowired
    private ModuleService moduleService;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute attribute) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection collection) {
// i have given this so that if user is not logged in then should not check permission at all 
        if(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)
            return ACCESS_DENIED;

             HttpServletRequest request = ((FilterInvocation) object).getHttpRequest();
    String requestedOperation = request.getParameter("operation");

    if (requestedOperation != null && !requestedOperation.isEmpty()){
        String [] requestURISplit = request.getRequestURI().split("/");
        String requestedModuleName = requestURISplit[2];

        if(SecurityUtils.hasPermission(requestedModuleName, requestedOperation)){
           return ACCESS_GRANTED;
        }
    } else {
        return ACCESS_GRANTED;
    }

    return ACCESS_DENIED;
```

Also, when I remove following lines from my voter, if the user is not logged in and tries to access the secured pages, it goes ahead. It should have redirected to the login page instead.

```
if(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)
                return ACCESS_DENIED;
```

This is the first time I am trying to use the spring boot. Hence, i am not sure of all the configuration issues.

Is there anything wrong with the order of the antMatchers?

Please help.

Comment: Why did you add the `AccessDecisionVoterImpl`?

Comment: I wanted to check if user has the required permissions to access the secured content. When user logins I am saving his authorities like addUser, activateUser etc in session. When he accesses a url i pass such permission in url and then check against the authorities in session. This is what i do in the AccessDecisionVoterImpl

Comment: Don't use `AccessDecisionVoter` for this. You can use `hasRole` in `antMatcher` for ensuring access rights

Comment: Could you replace `//// some other code to check role module based permissions. ` with real codes or at least some of them

Comment: Updated the code. Basically, module will be like user and operation on it will  be like addUser, deleteUser, listUser, editUser, activateUser, etc

Comment: Why you did not use something like `@PreAuthorize(hasRole('deleteUser'))` on your service methods? I see you've enabled the pre-post annotations

Comment: But then I will have to keep on adding such annotations everywhere. I though this would be a better way to have access check login at one place instead of having @PreAuthorize(hasRole('deleteUser')).

Comment: In fact I have successfully done this in the past using xml based configuration. This is the first time I am trying spring boot and java configuration.

Comment: Add java and spring tags

Comment: @anything what version of spring-boot / security are you using? can you post your pom.xml if you are using maven?

Comment: Can you test your code with ACCESS_ABSTAIN in stead of ACCESS_DENIED, and let know what happens?

Answer (score 4):

Your [`AccessDecisionVoter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionVoter.html) needs to either

- abstain from voting (`AccessDecisionVoter.ACCESS_ABSTAIN`): if the voter is unable to make a decision (eg. user unauthorized, unable to obtain module from request context etc.)
- grant access (`AccessDecisionVoter.ACCESS_GRANTED`): if the module can be identified and the user is authorized
- deny access (`AccessDecisionVoter.ACCESS_DENIED`): if the module can be identified and the user is not authorized

With your `AccessDecisionManager` configuration, you basically cancel out the url-based access restrictions such as:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/css/**", "/img/**", "/js/**", "/font/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/error**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/checkLogin**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
```

By default spring uses the [`WebExpressionVoter`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/expression/WebExpressionVoter.html) for that purpose.
However, the [`AffirmativeBased`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/AffirmativeBased.html) [AccessDecisionManager](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionManager.html) grants access if at least one AccessDecisionVoter grants access to a resource (this is probably not what you want).
For your requirements a [`ConsensusBased`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/ConsensusBased.html) AccessDecisionManager including the `WebExpressionVoter` would be the best match.

```
@Bean
public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
    List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = new ArrayList<>();
    decisionVoters.add(new WebExpressionVoter());
    decisionVoters.add(new ModuleAccessDecisionVoter());
    ConsensusBased consensusBased = new ConsensusBased(decisionVoters);

    // deny access if voters equally voted to allow and deny access
    consensusBased.setAllowIfEqualGrantedDeniedDecisions(false);
    return consensusBased;
}
```

Your `AccessDecisionVoter` implementation:

```
static class ModuleAccessDecisionVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<FilterInvocation> {

    public int vote(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
        if (authentication == null || authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            return ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        }

        // determine module and grant or deny access
        // if module cannot be determined abstain from voting
        String module = determineModule(object);
        if (module != null) {
            return isAccessGranted(module, authentication) ? ACCESS_GRANTED : ACCESS_DENIED
        }

        return ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
    }
}
```

---

Anonymous access should lead to the following results:

- `/login`: WebExpressionVoter: `+1`, ModuleVoter: `0` -> `1` = `ACCESS_GRANTED`
- `/foo-module`: WebExpressionVoter: `-1`, ModuleVoter: `-1` -> `-2` = `ACCESS_DENIED`

Given a User that is allowed to view the `Foo` module should produce the following results:

- `/foo-module`: WebExpressionVoter: `+1`, ModuleVoter: `+1` -> `2` = `ACCESS_GRANTED`
- `/bar-module`: WebExpressionVoter: `+1` (because user is authenticated), ModuleVoter: `-1` -> `0` = `ACCESS_DENIED` (because of `ConsensusBased.setAllowIfEqualGrantedDeniedDecisions(false)`)

Answer (score 2):

If I read this correctly, you are trying to solve the problem where your user is being logged in anonymously by returning ACCESS_DENIED for anonymous authentication. That's no good. Remove that custom code and instead do this in security config:

```
anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
```

Then, ensure that when user is logged in, they have the required role.

An alternative would be to disable anonymous login so you won't need roles (for long term this would not be recommended).

```
http.anonymous().disable()
```

Comment: No. Basically, what I am trying to do is to have module operation based authorization in the application. Any one with a valid login can login to the application. After login, Only those users who are authorized to access a particular operation will be allowed to access it. Anonymous users or ones who are not logged should still access the login page. But in my case , even the login page is not being shown to not loggged in users as it says access is denied.

Comment: Yes, jumped the gun a little on my response (edited). But if I understand it correctly, the problem is that because of custom authentication voter, you don't even get to the part where permitAll() would be checked so anonymous is not allowed to access any part of the application. It's much easier to distinguish non-anynomous logins by ensuring they have at least one user role (typically ROLE_USER).

Comment: Yes, how to get around that?

Comment: But shouldn't the voter get called after authentication and not before that?

Comment: The voter gets called on all secured resources. As such it gets checked even on login page, which the user would typically reach while logged in anonymously.

Comment: Ok, so if I remove it wouldn't the code to check module permission get called even for unauthenticated users. This is where its creating problem. Hence, I added that if condition in the voter. If the user is not logged in then it should not check for permissions.

Comment: If this is the only problem, just move the check to right before you call SecurityUtils with the module name (instead of checking even when operation parameter is not present), allowing normal procedure for other situations. This said, I would strongly urge to move the operation-specific security checks to your service classes with @Secured annotations as indicated by comments to original post.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from your voter.
Your voter should let anonymous access if the related "ConfigAttribute" is configured so.
Below is what you should add (it may depends on your Spring Security version):

```
for (ConfigAttribute attribute : collection) {
    if ("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY".equals(attribute.getAttribute())) {
        return ACCESS_GRANTED;
    }
}
```